# Are there different positions or manners to raise hands for du'a depending on the situation?

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, hadith-interpretation, sunnah, dua

My question is about the fiqh of du'a: In the sunnah we read:

- > Anas b. Malik reported that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) prayed for rain pointing **the back of his hands to the sky**. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/9/6))
- > The Prophet (ﷺ) said: When you make requests to Allah, do so with **the palms of your hands, and not backs, upwards**. ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/71))
- > When it was the day on which the Battle of Badr was fought, the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) cast a glance at the infidels, and they were one thousand while his own Companions were three hundred and nineteen. The Prophet (ﷺ) turned (his face) towards the Qibla. **Then he stretched his hands and began his supplication to his Lord** ...
  >   (From a long hadith which can be found in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/69) and elsewhere)
- > A man was **supplicating with his two fingers** so the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: “Make it one, make it one.” ([Jami' at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/188))

Do these ahadith and others refer to different ways (manners/positions) of performing du'a?

Is it considered as sunnah to chose a certain manner for a certain (reason of) du'a?